# How to Identify MongoDB Primary Server out of 'n' number of servers

Tags: mongodb, database

We have setup 4 servers, I wanted to know which one is acting as a Primary Server and the number of votes it has got from other server.

I know I can [Force a particular to act as Primary Server](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/)

**Question:** How to know that a particular server is Primary server at a given point of time?

In [member configuration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#member-configurations) we can set the priority like following:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].priority = 2
cfg.members[1].priority = 1
cfg.members[2].priority = 0.5
cfg.members[3].priority = 0
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

But still its not guaranteed that it will be a primary server. The statement in [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#secondary-only-members) says **"Member 0 to a priority of 2 so that it becomes primary, *under most circumstances.*"**

Can anyone know that how I can get to know my current primary server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know which node is primary at any given time then `rs.isMaster().primary` is command you need. It can be run on any node in a replicaset.